# Why is apache flink checkpoint size very large?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb, flink-cep

I've simple Apache Flink job: 
**DataSource (Apache Kafka) - Filter - KeyBy - CEP Pattern (with timer) - PatternProcessFucntion - KeyedProcessFunction (*here I've ValueState(Boolean) and registering timer on 5 minutes. If a valueState not null I'll update valueState (nothing to send in collector) and update timer. If a valueState is null, I'll save in state TRUE, then send input event in collector and setting timer. When onTimer method is ready, I'll clean my ValueState*) - Sink (Apache Kafka)**. 
Job settings: 
**Checkpointing interval: 5000ms** 
**Incremental checkpointing: true** 
**Semantic: Exactly Once** 
**State Backend: RocksDB** 
**Parallelism: 4** 
Logically my job is working perfectly, but I've some problems. 
I had two tests on my cluster (2 job manager and 3 task manager):
**First test:** 
I started my job and connected to an empty Apache Kafka topic then I saw in Flink WEB UI **Checkpointing Statistics:** 
1)Latest Acknowledgement - Trigger Time = 5000ms (like my checkpoint interval) 
2)State size = 340 kb at each 5sec interval 
3)All status was completed (blue). 
**Second test:**
I started sending json-messages with other keys (from "1" to Integer.MAX_VALUE) in Apache Kafka topic. Sending speed was: 1000 messages/sec then I saw in Flink WEB UI **Checkpointing Statistics:** 
1)Latest Acknowledgement - Trigger Time = 1 - 6 minutes 
**My Question #1: Why is this time growing? It is bad or OK?** 
2) State size was constantly growing. I sent messages in Kafka for about 10 minutes (1000 x 60 x 10 = 600000 messages). After sending State size was 100mb - 150mb. 
3)After sending I waited about an one hour and saw that:
Latest Acknowledgement - Trigger Time = 5000ms (like my checkpoint interval) 
State size was: 100mb - 150mb at each 5sec interval. 
 **My question #2: Why doesn't it decrease? After all I checked my job logs and saw 600000 records: ValueState for **key** was cleared (OnTimer method was successfully) and job logics (see description my KeyedProcessFunction) was working great** 
What was I trying to do? 
1)setting pause between checkpoints 
2)disable incremental checkpoints 
3)enable async checkpoints (in flink-conf.yml) 
It doesn't give any changes!!! 
**My question #3: What should I do?? Because on industrial server speed is: *10 millions messages/hour* and checkpoint size is increases instantly.**

Comment: Are you using Flink's CEP library?

Comment: Yes, David. I am using Flink CEP library.  But I always to use pattern with .within(Time.seconds(....))